# "disk does not contain a Windows XP-compatible partition” during installation?

Tags: windows, installation, partitioning

The machine I have has one SATA HDD with four partitions. I keep getting the error:

> disk does not contain a Windows XP-compatible partition

whatever I do.

I have plenty of free space, and just to let you know, I am running on an Ubuntu live boot, and also ran it before installing XP.

Comment: What are you trying to install?
Please describe what are the existing 4 partitions.

Comment: They are trying to install Windows XP, but I agree about needing to know what the existing partitions are.

Comment: Simple solution? Delete the partitions and do a fresh install, or just buy another HDD. They're pretty cheap nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

First Windows **HAS TO BE installed** on a **primary partition**.

I mean, if you have xp as well 7, then **one of them** can be on logical drive.

BUT, if if you have only one windows installation, it has to be on primary partition.

If all the 4 partitions are logical drives, the you need to repartition disk to have at least one primary partition ideally at the beginning of disk.

Use ubuntu live or gparted to check current partition layout and to repartition if required.

EDIT

Ahh...and what is the file system to those 4 partitions?(should be FAT32/NTFS)